# Support for a linear combination or transformation of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X, Y \sim iid U(0,1)$ and $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. In the linear combination $Z = c_1X+c_2Y$, we know that the probability density function of $Z$ depends on the relationships of $c_1$ and $c_2$.

For example, when $c_1 > c_2 > 0$, then the pdf of $Z$ is given by

$$ f(z) = \mathbf{1}_{0 \leq z \leq c_2} \dfrac{z}{c_1c_2} +\mathbf{1}_{c_2\leq z \leq c_1} \dfrac{c_2}{c_1c_2} + \mathbf{1}_{c_1 \leq z \leq c_1+c_2} \dfrac{c_1+c_2-z}{c_1c_2}.$$

The range of the support in this case is: $[0, c_1+c_2]$.

My questions are: what is a quick way to find the range of support when I change the conditions like (a) $c_1 >0$ but $c_2<0$ and (b) $c_1 < c_2 < 0$? I am not concerned about the pdf, just the support. Lastly, what will happen to the support of the pdf of $\sqrt{Z^2 -1}$, is there a quick way to find out?

EDIT: For $\sqrt{Z^2-1}$, I am interested to what the ranges of $c_1$ and $c_2$ that will make the result real or complex.

Comment: For $c_1\gt 0$, $c_2\lt 0$ the biggest possible value of $Z$ is $c_1$, and the smallest is $c_2$.

Comment: I just realized that $c_1 < c_2 < 0$ would simply mean that the range is $[-(c_1+c_2),0]$. How about for other transformations, like the one I mentioned above: $\sqrt{Z^2-1}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I did the $c_1\gt 0$, $c_2\lt 0$ because it is a little harder. For your square root, this is in many cases not a (real-valued) random variable. For example in the case $c_1\gt 0$, $c_2\lt 0$ we must insist that $c_1\le 1$ and $c_2\ge -1$.

Comment: I am interested to know also cases when it is complex.